# Multiple rows by number in cell

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table **multiple**:

```
CREATE TABLE multiple
(
    id int,
    Param1 int,
    Param2 int,
    Param3 int,
    Param4 int
);
INSERT INTO multiple VALUES 
    (1, 1, 2, 3, 0),
    (2, 3, 1, 0, 0),
    (3, 1, 2, 2, 1);
SELECT * FROM multiple;
```

I want to achieve with t-SQL new table like this: (Number of rows = Value in Param attributes)

```
Counter  ID TYPE
1        1  Param1
2        1  Param2
3        1  Param2
4        1  Param3
5        1  Param3
6        1  Param3
7        2  Param1
8        2  Param1
9        2  Param1
10       2  Param2
11       3  Param1
12       3  Param2
13       3  Param2
14       3  Param3
15       3  Param3
16       3  Param4
```

I adder here this text because I have error in editor that it looks like my post is mostly code;

Comment: Can you please write sample desc output,because images are blocked in our firewall

Comment: I think what you wants to `Achive` example in wrong .. can you please correct this .. here a clue `total count 1 in achive is 6` while ` .. your inserted 1 count is `5`

Comment: using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623321/convert-rows-into-columns-sql-server/33623941#33623941 .. your problem will get solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of ["tally tables"](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creative-solutions-by-using-a-number-table/)? They'll make quick work of this. Here is an example solution that uses one. It works by joining on each column where the number is <= the value in the Param attributes, giving you the number of rows you need. Then the id and type are selected.

Note this example uses a tally table that only counts up to 256, so if you need more, you can add an extra level - just be sure to put your tally table into a temp table otherwise it will go from taking a really fast time to execute, to being a really slow time.

```
CREATE TABLE multiple
(
    id int,
    Param1 int,
    Param2 int,
    Param3 int,
    Param4 int
);
INSERT INTO multiple VALUES 
    (1, 1, 2, 3, 0),
    (2, 3, 1, 0, 0),
    (3, 1, 2, 2, 1);
SELECT * FROM multiple;


-- Tally table known as a "Ben-Gan" style Tally
WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
    ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
    ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
    ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
    ,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv3)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) [Counter],
    Id,
    [Type]
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, 'Param1' AS [Type] FROM multiple INNER JOIN Tally ON multiple.Param1 >= Tally.n UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, 'Param2' AS [Type] FROM multiple INNER JOIN Tally ON multiple.Param2 >= Tally.n UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, 'Param3' AS [Type] FROM multiple INNER JOIN Tally ON multiple.Param3 >= Tally.n UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, 'Param4' AS [Type] FROM multiple INNER JOIN Tally ON multiple.Param4 >= Tally.n
) [single]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can use following code to achieve your goal :

```
CREATE TABLE multiple
(
    id int,
    Param1 int,
    Param2 int,
    Param3 int,
    Param4 int
);
INSERT INTO multiple VALUES 
    (1, 1, 2, 3, 0),
    (2, 3, 1, 0, 0),
    (3, 1, 2, 2, 1);

SELECT * FROM multiple;

CREATE TABLE multiple1
(
    ID int,
    TYPE VARCHAR(10)
)
DECLARE @id int = 0

WHILE (@id<=(SELECT Count(id) FROM multiple))
BEGIN
DECLARE @Count int = 0
DECLARE @Count1 int = 0
DECLARE @Count2 int = 0
DECLARE @Count3 int = 0

    WHILE(@Count<(SELECT Param1 FROM  multiple where id = @id)) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO multiple1 VALUES ((Select id from multiple where id = @id),'Param1')
        SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END
    WHILE(@Count1<(SELECT Param2 FROM  multiple where id = @id)) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO multiple1 VALUES ((Select id from multiple where id = @id),'Param2')
        SET @Count1 = @Count1 + 1
    END
    WHILE(@Count2<(SELECT Param3 FROM  multiple where id = @id)) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO multiple1 VALUES ((Select id from multiple where id = @id),'Param3')
        SET @Count2 = @Count2 + 1
    END
    WHILE(@Count3<(SELECT Param4 FROM  multiple where id = @id)) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO multiple1 VALUES ((Select id from multiple where id = @id),'Param4')
        SET @Count3 = @Count3 + 1
    END

    SET @id = @id + 1
END

SELECT * FROM multiple1
```